# Append several elements and not a single one with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a new div which holds one comment. However, on the front-end I only get back one, even though the length of the array is more than 1.

```
success: function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  console.log(data)
  for(i=1;i < data.length;i++) {
    var comment = $("<div><div>"+data[i][1]+"</div><div>"+data[i][2]+"</div><div>"+data[i][3]+"</div><div>"+data[i][4]+"</div></div>")
    $('.comments').append(comment)
```

Comment: Could it be that your array has 2 items, yet you see only 1? The fix: use **`for (var i = 0; ... )`**. The first item in all Javascript arrays is found at index [0].

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're excluding the first element from the array, you have to include the element of index 0 :

```
for(i=0;i < data.length;i++)
```

Comment: I highly recommend `var i = 0;` instead of just `i=0;`. It's rare that you'll ever need `i` in the global scope, and it can produce undesirable results if you re-use it later.